# Custom Post Type Name Causing Problem

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, wp-admin, wp-list-pages

Please ignore my poor English.

I have custom post type `(order)`. and its working like charm,

But default post type `(pages)` list are not displaying in `wp-admin` side.

You can see More information in attached screenshots.

Please help me guys to figure out what is the problem.

**For Order Post Type:-** 
[image]

**For Pages:-** 
[image]

I have added following code:

```
add_action('init', 'create_post_type');
function create_post_type()
{
    register_post_type('order',
            array(
                    'labels' => array(
                            'name' => __('Orders'),
                            'edit_item' => __('Edit Order'),
                            'add_new' => __('New Order'),
                            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Order'),
                            'singular_name' => __('Orders')
                    ),
                    'public' => true,
                    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields')
            )
    );
}
```

Comment: Please share the code with which you activated your `order` CPT. Somehow it seems it's the culprit.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam see my updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` is a reserved term, the best - I know of - overview over those can be found here: [Codex: `register_taxonomy()` - Reserved Terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms). The list is in it's relevance not restricted to taxonomies. The introduction to it does make it clear(er) why:

> Avoiding the following reserved terms is particularly important if you are passing the term through the $_GET or $_POST array. Doing so can cause WordPress to respond with a 404 error without any other hint or explanation.

Comment: `order` is a reserved term for `taxonomy`. I think order is not reserved for `post_type`.

Comment: Thats not exactly true, using the terms - and term does mean word here, more than term as part of a taxonomy - from that list can lead to problems in many other places. @AkshayPãghdÂr

Comment: These reseved named **does not** only apply to taxonomy names, but to any naming convention. They should be avoided accross the board, not just taxonomies

Answer (score 3):

This is actaully  a naming clash. Wordpress uses the word `order` in its core as a sorting function, and is also a reserved name that should not be used by themes or plugins

Changing your custom post type name to `orders` will fix your problem

Comment: Yes, post type name `orders` does work but i cant change that. beacause, there are lots of place i have used `order` as post type name, also i have integrated CI `codeigniter` with this and using through API.

Comment: I have tried to find solution for this but didn't get much help, i think WordPress will not allow this post type name.\

Comment: Then you have a serious issue. Naming conventions is the most important thing to look out for. Never use anything that might clash with core used names. The only solution here would be to pain stakingly change each instance of `order` and maybe use a rewrite rule to rewrite your url to `order`

Comment: You are right, you cannot use the name `order`. There is no solution to this, only soluytion is to change your cpt name, and work from there

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an action to 'pre_get_posts' that it's excluding the page post-type.
Paste that code here, so we can help you.

Comment: I have updated question with code, and i didn't use `pre_get_posts` anywhere.

Comment: Change the theme to a default theme, can check if the problem continues. Also do you have pages? :)

Comment: Thank you for reply, but i have tried all the way, like changing theme, deactivate all plugin, but didn't solve the problem. and yes i have 18 pages.

Comment: Please refer attached images.